# Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects from Nuget..., Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smo

I've added the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects (140.17235.0) from Nuget to an Asp.Net MVC application and am getting an error immediately upon running.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

I've tried to check the PublicKeyToken on the this dll that gets copied into the bin folder and I get the same error using Powershell

([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll")).FullName

What am I missing here?  If I remove the dll from the bin folder and refresh the error page, the app works..., but not sure what functionality uses this dll...

I've tried adding it and removing many times..., to no avail...

Comment: Last I checked the SMO libraries are only unofficially available in Nuget. You get the real ones by choosing the appropriate features during the setup of MSSQL Server. Check the author of the package and don't blindly trust everything in Nuget.

Comment: The author is Microsoft...  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/

Comment: OK, things may have changed since last I checked. But I'm still suspicious that a package from Microsoft would have an invalid signature. Maybe try one of the previous versions just to see if there is a difference?

Comment: Looks like they screwed up the signing in the most recent version...  the previous versions seem to work just fine.  odd.